# Only apply hover selector on input not label

Tags: html, css

How would you prevent a hover selector being applied when the user hovers over an input label, it should only be applied when hovering over the input.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.input:hover,
.input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="forename">Forename</label>
<input id="forename" name="forename" class="input" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are binding those two elements (as far as the browser is concerned) you need to apply another rule for the label hover specifically.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.input:hover,
.input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  outline: none;
}

label:hover + .input {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<label for="forename">Forename</label>
<input id="forename" name="forename" class="input" />
```